# Is it okay to showcase templates/layouts recreated in different codes in a portfolio?

Tags: web-development, website-design, website-features

I have several different templates/layouts, both simple and complex. I recreated these templates multiple times, just using different codes. (Say, a complex one was originally made in only HTML and CSS, I *recreated* it using HTML, Javascript, CSS, then again with a HTML and PHP concoction, and etc.)

I wanted to showcase my work and skills by doing this, but I don't know if it would be okay for that all to go into a resumé/portfolio. This is why:

- **Freelancing** Does potential business really care about how their site is made, as long as it looks and functions to their liking? (As in, should I just only show the one example of each template/layout and not the multiple recreations?)
- **Potential Hire** However, if a potential employer were to stumble across my resumé/portfolio, would having the multiple recreations do any good for a career outlook? (As in, this potential employer is a company where I could be working on a team to create/develop sites and not be freelancing; would a lack of skill-shining turn this employer away because I didn't set myself apart and show that I'm not just like every other budding web designer?)

Those two issues have me wondering if it is okay to have a resumé/portfolio combined for this specific reason. Or does something like this not matter to potential business (as a freelancer) because they wouldn't care either way *as long as it looks and functions to their liking* and therefore it is okay to showcase the recreations with the originals?

Comment: Do what works for you - if it is different to the way others do it, be proud.

Comment: @Steve It wouldn't be too much, then? (Like overdoing it?)

Comment: If you are worried about it, maybe show one template and then "click for variations" or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen some web development companies showcase "their" work / screen shots which turned out to be the same thumbnails used on the template sites for those templates. That I think is about as low as you go. But if they really aren't designers and simply install templates configure them with a companies information that's ok as long as the company is happy with the work.

If you've modified a template or created one from scratch with variations I don't see any reason not to use them in your portfolio. This is something you'll have to decide on. There's no way for you to know if a company looking at your portfolio with like or dislike it based on the likeness of each template. So the safe way to go would be use the variations that are the most different from one another. You can always send references as needed.

Comment: So what your second paragraph suggests (in the first part), is that it is a good thing all of my work is original! ;) Now, the second part of your second paragraph, I'm a bit lost. The template/layouts themselves are all drastically different. My question was, should I also post up the same template/layouts that were variations of their originals to show how much knowledge I know. (So let's say a guy doesn't really care for interactive webpages, so javascript is out, but he really likes the one layout.) (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued)(So would it be a good thing to show that I can do the same layout without the javascript... like let's say he's only into very simple HTML&CSS...) Would it be a good thing that I have the variations of these layouts in my portfolio/resume as well? Or would it be better if I just detail (like list) what other variations of that same template/layout come in? --So far, I really like your answer, I just would like a little clarification on your second half before I make this 'best answer'. :D I'm very appreciative of you taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Souta you can show a before and after or template variations. If you have a template that is pure HTML/CSS, another 100% the same but uses some Javascript I wouldn't post them in a portfolio. Most people aren't tech savvy and you may confuse them which might make them leave your site. Maybe write a blog post about a project that required you to change a site from HTML to incorporate some jQuery/Javascript and link to your portfolio. Be brief in your portfolio list HTML/CSS/jQuery/AJAX near the thumbnails. On a services page feel free to list all your skills.

Comment: @Souta another couple of suggestions google various web design and development phrases with the word portfolio. Also look around themeforest.net and look at portfolio themes to get an idea of how you can layout your portfolio and what information to include.